# How to create userrole that have permission to create other users, like sub users of the headquarter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a system build in ruby on rails. We using rails admin to display all data.

We will have 3 different types of clients, Client1 (carshop), client2 (Headquarters with many carshop, like fransice) client3 (Subcontractors)

Client 1, and client2 is basicly same type of client, but but client2 have a headquarter, and many carshops below as a chain.

The headquarter should be able to view all data from all the carshop that belong to headquarter, create user logins for each shops, but all shops is independent from 1 shop to another (The shops that belongs to the headquarters cant see each other data, like order historic)

Hope my question make sense to you.

Thank you in advange.

trying to create a user that have permission to create sub users that belongs to the users admin panel, but only can see data that the user have given permission to.

Comment: I would model it with users belonging to a company and companies can (optional) belong to another parent company. Then you can model the access rights by defining that a user is allowed to manage their company's data and all optional subcompanies' data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks im gonna try this. 

I got a new problem, and I cant really see what the problem is here. Now it will not show me the list of clients. 

Do you have an idea why? 

Showing /home/freshlykim/Dev/Ruby/Dolls/app/views/clients/index.html.slim where line #35 raised:

uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007fc593667910>::Show
Extracted source (around line #35):
        td = client.collection_locations.size
        td = client.orders.size
        td = link_to  Show , client   <---PROBLEM HERE

Comment: Impossible to tell without being able to see your code. I suggest opening a new question for this problem.